# Can I restore my user that has been wiped during the Monterey update?

Tags: monterey

Monterey thought I would appreciate that it removed my user of 7 years from my system

I can see the data for the user still exists (Downloads etc) but since Monterey first boot, it asked me to create a user and I am logged into that now but all my user settings from the 7 year old account are not applied

Is there another fix to just revert and go back to how it was working before the Monterey update?

I have a Time Machine backup from yesterday but I can only see methods for restoring particular files of a date. I only want to go back to how my machine was setup yesterday as this is my development machine and my setup was very important to me

Edit:

This issue was caused by Monterey creating itself a new disk partition

Updating the startup disk, in system settings, to the original partition solved the issue for me

Comment: Do you know your macOS version prior to the upgrade? An erase install would get you a clean slate to [restore all files from the backup](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/recover-all-your-files-mh15638/mac)

Comment: I think i've identified what has caused the issue. Monterey has installed itself on a new partition. I can still see my old user and data. This is a nightmare :(

@bmike - So it's possible for me to restore my system (against High Sierra) if I have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: It may not be that bad - the system and user data volumes are distinct by design. The system likely made a snapshot and you may be able to restore to the past checkpoint.

Comment: @bmike - I have changed my startup disk to be the original and I am now back in Big Sur under my usual user

Now to remove the Monterey partition and resist the update for as long as possible

Comment: Awesome!  I would post a completely new thread with diskutil list output if you want cleanup help. That is easy. Suppressing updates can be tricky as well